# What are 32.1.*.* when updating root hints in Windows 2003 DNS?

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system

I'm updating root hints on a Windows 2003 server, and I push "Copy from server" and type in the IP address of a known root server, e.g. 198.41.0.4 (a.root-servers.net).

When I do this, a number of servers get an address in 32.1.*.* in addition to their real address.  What is happening?

I get:

```
32.1.5.0 for h.root-servers.net
32.1.7.254 for i.root-servers.net
32.1.5.3 for j.root-servers.net
32.1.7.253 for k.root-servers.net
32.1.13.195 for m.root-servers.net.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows 2003 DNS is misinterpreting an IPv6 address.

For instance, it gets 2001:7FE::53 for i.root-servers.net.

It takes the first four octets (20, 01, 07 and FE) and thinks they are actually the four bytes of an IPv4 address (ie 32.1.7.253).

The best thing to do is to just go through the root hints and remove all these spurious, incorrect results.